# how to adapt withStyles for mui v5?

Tags: react-with-styles

If we have a legacy MUI snippet like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import Paper from '@material-ui/core/Paper';
import Grid from '@material-ui/core/Grid';
import Hidden from '@material-ui/core/Hidden';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';
const styles = theme => ({
root: {
flexGrow: 1
},
paper: {
padding: theme.spacing(2),
textAlign: 'center',
color: theme.palette.text.secondary
}
});
const ColumnDirection = withStyles(styles)(({ classes }) => (
<div className={classes.root}>
<Grid container justify="space-around" spacing={4}>
<Grid item xs={3}>
<Grid container direction="column" spacing={2}>
```

How do we realize the same functionality in mui v5?

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace all `@material-ui/core` to `@mui/material` to import components and use `makeStyles` function (which returns hook) instead of `withStyles` hoc.

```
import React from 'react';
import { makeStyles } from "@mui/styles"; // withStyles substitute
import Paper from '@mui/material/Paper';
import Grid from '@mui/material/Grid';
import Hidden from '@mui/material/Hidden';
import Typography from '@mui/material/Typography';

const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
   root: {
     flexGrow: 1
   },
   paper: {
     padding: theme.spacing(2),
     textAlign: 'center',
     color: theme.palette.text.secondary
   }
}));

const ColumnDirection = () => {
  const classes = useStyles();

 return (
   <div className={classes.root}>
     <Grid container justify="space-around" spacing={4}>
     <Grid item xs={3}>
     <Grid container direction="column" spacing={2}>
```

Answer (score 0):

### Update 2024: @mui/style is deprecated and now we need to use styled from "@mui/system" to customize mui component or use css classes

From official docs:
@mui/styles was deprecated with the release of MUI Core v5 in late 2021. It depended on JSS as a styling solution, which is no longer used in @mui/material.

@mui/styles is not compatible with React.StrictMode or React 18, and it will not be updated.

Reference: https://mui.com/system/styles/api/